# Adding npm webpage to my ASP.net Core App

Tags: node.js, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, npm, npm-install

I've running webApp in asp.net core. I need to add a webpage that uses npm package how to create it and route to it and ensure that all files were published with the build

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your description, if you want to use npm to install the package, I suggest you could refer to below steps:

1.You should make sure you have installed the [npm](https://nodejs.org/en/download/)

2.You should add the package.json file, right-click the project in Solution Explorer and choose Add > New Item. Choose the npm Configuration File, use the default name, and click Add.

[image]

If you don't see the npm Configuration File listed, Node.js development tools are not installed. You can use the Visual Studio Installer to add the Node.js development workload. Then repeat the previous step.

3.Include one or more npm packages in the dependencies or devDependencies section of package.json. For example, you might add the following to the file:

```
"devDependencies": {
   "gulp": "4.0.2",
   "@types/jquery": "3.3.33"
}
```

More details, you could refer to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/javascript/npm-package-management?view=vs-2019#npmAdd).